# Data from database of last 10 newest

Tags: php, mysql

I just wanna show last 10 or 30 depends on list if there is big data, searched over the net but all by correcting I can see only the 1st data not newest one.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, tag, count FROM url ORDER BY id, tag, count ASC LIMIT 1";
```

I am testing with two datat on database and want to display last one but all the time it shows the oldest one (first data), I changed ASC and DESC also, both time result is same.

Comment: you need to use ORDER BY id DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one:

```
$Query = "SELECT id, tag, count FROM url ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

Order by id using "DESC" it get last to first and limit 0,10 means it display last 10 record

```
$sql = "SELECT id, tag, count FROM url ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 10"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query & try this:

```
$Query = "SELECT id, tag, count FROM url ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
```